# Override base class methods in derived class and fire its event

Tags: c#, event-handling, overriding

I want to Override base class methods in derived class and then do something in derived class. therefore the base class method be invoked with its generic type . Then I aim to fire the derived class method which is overridden.

I have below codes :

```
    public class Service<T> : Interface.IService<T> where T : class
    {

    public virtual event System.EventHandler<EntitySavingEventArgs<T>> BeforeSavingRecord;

    public Service()
    {

    }

    public virtual void OnBeforeSavingRecord(object sender, EntitySavingEventArgs<T> e)
    {

    }

    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    public Service(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public virtual void Create(T item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");

        BeforeSavingRecord?.Invoke(this, new EntitySavingEventArgs<T>() { SavedEntity = item });
        _dbContext.Set(typeof(T)).Add(item);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and in its derrived classes I have something like this :

```
[Service]
public partial class BankBusiness : Service<Bank>, IBankBusiness
{
    public BankBusiness()
        : base(ContainerManager.Container.Resolve<MyContext>())
    {

    }


    public override void OnBeforeSavingRecord(object sender, EntitySavingEventArgs<Bank> e)
    {
        //Do something with entity item before saving
        base.OnBeforeSavingRecord(sender, e);
    }
}
```

And then in my controllers when I call

```
bankBiz.Create(new Bank() { ... });
```

I want to fire bankBiz (derrived class) overridden method (OnBeforeSavingRecord) which is registered to BeforeSavingRecord event.

I donot know if my scenario is correct and if it is right how i can fire it.

if it is not correct what I should do.

Comment: does this line: `BeforeSavingRecord?.Invoke(this, new EntitySavingEventArgs<T>() { SavedEntity = item });` not lead to the firing of the event?

Comment: it does. But I do not want to call it in my derived classes. I want to do something just with overriding, the overridden method be called.

Comment: then I did not really understand you. You wrote: "Then I aim to fire the derived class method which is overridden." the only overridden method I see in your posted code is `public override void OnBeforeSavingRecord`.

Comment: Calling `OnBeforeSavingRecord` in the method `Create` will execute first the code in the overriden method of the derived class if you call it from an instance of the derived class. Please check out my edfit

Comment: thanks man. Your solution works but not in my case . check out my last post please

Comment: Is `bankBiz` an instance of `Service<...>` or `BankBusiness` ? And where do you call `OnBeforeSavingRecord`?

Comment: It's an instance of BankBusiness  which its implementation is in Service<T> which is the Baseclass of BankBusiness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mong Zhu your solution works but not for my scenario . I came up with the below solution

```
public class Service<T> : Interface.IService<T> where T : class
{

    Interface.IService<T> implementation;

    public virtual event System.EventHandler<EntitySavingEventArgs<T>> BeforeSavingRecord;

    public virtual event System.EventHandler<EntitySavingEventArgs<T>> SavingRecord;

    public virtual event System.EventHandler<EntitySavingEventArgs<T>> RecordSaved;

    public void PopulateEvents(Interface.IService<T> _implementation)
    {
        implementation = _implementation;

        implementation.BeforeSavingRecord += new System.EventHandler<EntitySavingEventArgs<T>>(this.OnBeforeSavingRecord);
        implementation.SavingRecord += new System.EventHandler<EntitySavingEventArgs<T>>(this.OnSavingRecord);
        implementation.RecordSaved += new System.EventHandler<EntitySavingEventArgs<T>>(this.OnRecordSaved);
    }

    public virtual void OnBeforeSavingRecord(object sender, EntitySavingEventArgs<T> e)
    {

    }

    public virtual void OnSavingRecord(object sender, EntitySavingEventArgs<T> e)
    {

    }
    public virtual void OnRecordSaved(object sender, EntitySavingEventArgs<T> e)
    {

    }

    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    public Service(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public virtual void Create(T item)
    {

        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");

        BeforeSavingRecord?.Invoke(this, new EntitySavingEventArgs<T>() { SavedEntity = item });
        _dbContext.Set(typeof(T)).Add(item);
        SavingRecord?.Invoke(this, new EntitySavingEventArgs<T>() { SavedEntity = item });
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        RecordSaved?.Invoke(this, new EntitySavingEventArgs<T>() { SavedEntity = item });

    }
}
```

and the derived class :

```
    [Service]
public partial class BankBusiness : Service<Bank>, IBankBusiness
{
    public BankBusiness()
        : base(ContainerManager.Container.Resolve<MyContext>())
    {
        base.PopulateEvents(this);
    }


    public override void OnBeforeSavingRecord(object sender, EntitySavingEventArgs<Bank> e)
    {

        base.OnBeforeSavingRecord(sender, e);
    }
}
```

which the point is

```
base.PopulateEvents(this);
```

Comment: I still don't really get what you have asked for. You were missing the point where you have to register the events?

Comment: could you explain what difference it makes between using `BeforeSavingRecord?.Invoke(this...` and `OnBeforeSavingRecord(this, ...` ? I think I did not get the point right. I am just reading about it

Comment: I wanted to use those events not the methods. using events I can register some other methods in some cases and fire them all just by invoking the event. but by calling the method, it's not possible

Comment: that sounds like a good reason. Did not think about that. Thanx for the explanation and enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar pattern implemented in the base class I did it in a way like this:

**Base:**

```
public virtual void OnBeforeSavingRecord(object sender, EntitySavingEventArgs<T> e)
{    }
```

and in the derived class I had exactly the call that you use:

**Derivied:**

```
public override void OnBeforeSavingRecord(object sender, EntitySavingEventArgs<Bank> e)
{
    //Do something with entity item before saving
    base.OnBeforeSavingRecord(sender, e);
}
```

To fire the event in my case it was sufficient to just call

```
OnBeforeSavingRecord(this, new EntitySavingEventArgs<T>() { SavedEntity = item });
```

and the whole scenario worked for me.

EDIT:

Calling `OnBeforeSavingRecord` will executed the code in the overriden method of the derived class if you call it from an instance of the derived class!

If I understand you right you want to fire the event in the method `Create` but want the event code of the derived class executed. It will be if the event is overridden like in your case. You could test it with this simple Console application: (just copy paste and run)

```
public class Service 
{
    public virtual event System.EventHandler<EventArgs> BeforeSavingRecord;

    public virtual void OnBeforeSavingRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base: OnBeforeSavingRecord method call");
    }

    public virtual void Create(object item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base: Create method call");
        // this will call the method of the derived class! if you call it from an instance of the derived class
        OnBeforeSavingRecord(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public partial class BankBusiness : Service
{
    public override void OnBeforeSavingRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something with entity item before saving
        Console.WriteLine("Derived Class OnBeforeSavingRecord CALL");

        base.OnBeforeSavingRecord(sender, e);                
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{        
    BankBusiness bankBiz = new BankBusiness();

    bankBiz.Create(new object());

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I do not want to call OnBeforeSavingRecord in my Derived class. I want to make an approach  to just have overridden method in my Derived class and the base be called when I use Create method